# Goal copy-dependencies in maven-dependency-plugin is not executed

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have the following plugin configuration :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

When calling `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` dependencies are indeed copied, and at the correct location (`alternateLocation`). But when I'm calling `mvn package` nothing is performed. What am I missing ?

Comment: As visible below, the solution consists of moving the <plugin> element inside a <plugins> element that is within <build>, and not within <build><pluginManagement>

Answer (score -1):

As per [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html#dependency:copy-dependencies), you need to have your `configuration` **inside** the `execution`.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <!-- configure the plugin here -->
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: I tried that but the goal is still not executed when called `mvn package`
Actually, putting the configuration above actually makes at least my life easier since I can simply call `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`

Comment: This answer is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

We only see parts of your POM, but I guess you put the plugin into `<pluginManagement>` and not into `<plugins>` where it belongs.

Comment: My <plugin> section is placed into     <project><build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

Comment: That is the wrong place. Move it out of plugin management.

Comment: That was the thing !!  Thanks @J Fabian Meier

 Indeed configurations and execution can be placed either in <pluginManagement><plugins> or just <plugins>. It looks like what is in <pluginManagement> gets overridden by the super-pom.